# r - show ticks for rangeslider (plotly)

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, rangeslider

Is there a way to show the x-axis (or ticks) for a rangeslider created with plotly, i.e. another x-axis (ticks) for the subplot created. In this way it would be easier to select a desired range.

Here is an example from the plotly documentation creating a plot with a rangeslider:

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

# Download some data
getSymbols(Symbols = c("AAPL", "MSFT"))

ds <- data.frame(Date = index(AAPL), AAPL[,6], MSFT[,6])

plot_ly(ds, x = ~Date) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~AAPL.Adjusted, name = "Apple") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~MSFT.Adjusted, name = "Microsoft") %>%
  layout(
    title = "Stock Prices",
    xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
    yaxis = list(title = "Price"))
```

I looked in the documentation for the rangeslider argument (https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-rangeslider) but this function doesn't take an argument for ticks. Does anybody know of a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not know R but after reading suggest looking [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-yaxis-type). May be set `type=date` need be written in `xaxis` but not `in rangeslider`?